# Display specific page to all connected users, after userA clicks button - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, signalr

I have Xamarin.Forms frontend app and Web API .NET Core backend and I use SignalR. I am able to make chat - userA sends a message and all connected users can see it.

And now I need to display specific page to all connected users after userA clicks the button. I have created DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers SignalR client method but I don’t know how to tell there to display specific page to all connected users. Thanks for any advice

**Xamarin.Forms - SignalRClient.cs**

```
public class SignalRClient : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private HubConnection Connection;
    public delegate void MessageReceived(string username, string message);
    public event MessageReceived OnMessageReceived;

    public SignalRClient(string url)
    {
        Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(url)
             .Build();

        Connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (username, text) =>
        {
            OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(username, text);
        });

        Connection.On("DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers", () =>
        {
           //??display specific page to all connected users??                 
        });
    }

    public void SendMessage(string username, string text)
    {
        Connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", username, text);           
    }

    public void DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers()
    {
        Connection.InvokeAsync("DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers");              
    }

    public Task Start()
    {
         return Connection.StartAsync(); 
    }
```

**Backend - ChatHub.cs**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
    public async Task DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers");
    }
}
```

### *** Edit ***

Instead of MainPage I have to put SignalRClient and it is working if I use MessagingCenter without using SignalR. See bellow

In SignalRClient.cs

```
    public void DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers()
    {
        //Connection.InvokeAsync("DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers");
        MessagingCenter.Send<SignalRClient>(this, "MyPage"); //working
    }
```

But it is not working as soon as I use SignalR

```
        Connection.On("DisplayPageToAllConnectedUsers", () =>
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<SignalRClient>(this, "MyPage");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MessagingCenter, to send a message to your MainPage, to redirect the application to whatever page you want. For example:

In SignalRClient.cs

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "ChangeToYourPage");
```

In your MainPage.xaml.cs, you subscribe to this event:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "ChangeToYourPage", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "ChangeToYourPage" message is sent
    Navigation.PushAsync(YourNewPage);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it’s very useful info! Unfortunatelly it is not working with SignalR see edit

Comment: You have to send it to your page that is available to redirect ,. in your SignalR, you just send the event. See my answer.

Comment: Problem was with threads, now it is working with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread().. thank you